# How to Export/Import Toolbars in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, settings

I export my settings in Visual Studio and if I ever move to a new machine or have problems, I use those backed up settings to restore Visual Studio to the way I like it. It also allows me to maintain a consistent development environment between the various machines that I use.

This works great for keybindings, syntax highlighting, user tools, pretty much everything except for the **toolbar locations** and **customizations**. Whenever I move to a new machine and restore the settings, the toolbars are not affected. I have spent a fair amount of time setting up toolbars with my macros, external tools, etc and cut'n'pasted icons in for them. I hate losing all that work.

Does anybody know how to back up and restore the toolbars' locations and customizations? If it is not a feature of Visual Studio, is there an addin that will do the job?

**Edit**

As mentioned below, the *Menu and Command Bar Customizations* in *Import and Export Settings* is supposed to do this, but when I re-import my previous settings, I get

> Error 1:  Menu and Command Bar Customizations: The version of command bar settings being imported is not supported. All the command bar settings have been ignored.

The settings I am trying to re-import were exported earlier this month with the same version of Visual Studio. The only difference is that I am now running 64 bit as opposed to x86. I didn't think that would make a difference though since the settings files are XML.

Any ideas?

Comment: All the info here is geared towards saving personal settings. Is there a good way to share a custom toolbar across a team of developers? (And automatically update it?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to this. There is a [known bug in Visual Studio](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=105493) and there are [two workarounds given](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=105493). The first workaround does not apply, but the second worked.

To Backup your toolbars:

> Copy the file **CmdUI.PRF** from the path **%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\X.Y\1033** to the same directory as your exported .settings file. 
>   where **X.Y is either of 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 or 11.0** depending on your visual studio version (2005, 2008, 2010 and 2012 respectively).

To Restore your toolbars:

> Make sure Visual Studio is closed and copy the backed up file back to the original location.

Comment: **%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033\cmdui.prf** for **VS2010**

Comment: This is incredible. This answer/hack was posted 10 years ago and  VS2017 still has this same issue! Btw, this answer is worded kinda wrong. What basically worked for me is after I did the documented export and then import in VS, was to close it and then copy `CmdUI.prf` from the source `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\A.B\1033` folder to the destination `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\C.D\1033` folder. Where `A.B` is the version of VS where you're copying toolbars from and `C.D` is the version of the VS where you're copying them to. (I did it on the same computer though.)

Answer (score 10):

For the benefit of others, as you mentioned this feature doesn't seem to be supported across versions of Visual Studio, presumably because of a change in the DTD/XSD for the settings file? At any rate, here's where the settings for your custom toolbars lie in the "Import and Export Settings..." dialog:

[image]

*Note: Your options may look different, depending on the settings you exported.*

Comment: Thanks, it is nice to see that it is finally supported in VS2012. I assume that is what this screenshot is from?

Comment: @RobProuse No actually, this was tagged as VS2008, so I took a screenshot from that version. I believe this was supported even in 2005 if I'm not mistaken. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it, but "Tools\Import and Export Settings..." maybe will let you export a .vssettings file you can then take to another box.

See also

http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2005/04/19/409887.aspx

and other Sara 'export' tips.

Comment: Make sure you have "Menu and Command Bar Customisation" ticked. It works for me (at least with a custom made toolbar).